# how to load data table's column values to listbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have a data table variable called `_dataTable` which contains a data table which holds a single column . How can I load the `_dataTable`'s row values to a `ListBox` without using the `DataSource` property ? I have to manipulate the data in the `ListBox` later on so using a `DataSource` don't allow user to edit the `ListBox`.
Code examples will be appreciated .

Thank you

Comment: Winforms or webforms? Also, even if you use it as datasource you can edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `DataSource` you can fill it manually:

```
foreach(DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
    listBox.Items.Add(row[0]);
```

But even if you use the `DataSource` you could modify  the `DataTable` later.

Answer (score 1):

```
   string yourvalue = _dataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]
```

Should do it

Indexes are 0 based so we first access the first row (0) and then the 1th column in the row (0)

or

you can also use this:-

```
string yourvalue =  _dataTable.Rows[0]["column name"].ToString();
```

Add this value to your list box, i am assuming listbox1 is the id of your listbox

```
listbox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(yourvalue));
```

Comment: How does this show how to fill the ListBox without `DataSource`?

Comment: ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(yourvalue)), where ListBox1 is id of ListBox